# How to make "Open File..." window in netbeans PLATFORM?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I need to create something like internal frame in netbeans *platform*, which loads file from any location.
I tried it by jInternalFrame, but I was not able to find some container to which I can add my frame. I am working in netbeans **platform**, which has own pre-created main window.

Pease help me by any advice, I am dealing with this about 10 hours, still without result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow()` as parent for `JFileChooser` dialog.